# rails - root model or application model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I was just looking around rails and noticed there is an app controller but no app model.

Is there no root model in rails ? if not where do you put a piece of code that needs to be in every model.

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nothing says your controllers have to subclass `ApplicationController` but it generally is the standard because the vast majority of rails applications make use of the `layout` capabilities (which can vary on each controller), so instead of forcing the rare ones without layouts from turning the layout off (`layout nil` or `layout false`) for each controller, they make an 'abstract' one that you can turn controller features on and off easily for your whole application.

Now for models, you could create an `ApplicationModel` for all of your models to subclass, but there are two things to think about:

1. ActiveRecord normally detects when you subclass an already subclassed `ActiveRecord::Base` and uses this to turn STI (single table inheritance) on.
2. `ApplicationModel` will be an actual model that is expected to have a table in your database. This can lead to problems down the line.

To fix these two problems, you have to set `abstract_class` to true for ActiveRecord to properly function.

```
class ApplicationModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

In contrast to an abstract ActionController, `abstract_class` *must* set to true which means the developer must know they cannot remove this line from `ApplicationModel`. With `ApplicationController` you can do pretty much whatever you want to it.

Comment: Wish I could have +1'ed you a bazillion times.  Was looking into why I was having issues when trying to subclass my models into an ApplicationModel.

Comment: In Rails v5 an "ApplicationRecord has been born as a default parent class of all models created by the generators". See Rails 5.0.0.beta1 release notes: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2015/12/18/Rails-5-0-beta1/

Comment: Thank you, couldn't fine anywhere about that abstract class, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Most models in rails inherit from ActiveRecord::Base which has all of the conventional getters and setters and the association methods, validations and support.

You could extend ActiveRecord::Base in a file in the lib directory (or anywhere in the rails load path really) and any models that are active record models would have the method(s) available. Modules are also a good way of sharing code between many models.

Answer (score -1):

I think I remember some years ago, there actually existed a ann AppModel by default. Is this true or do I mix things up (I haven't been working with Rails for some years until now)?